# python inspect get methods decorated with @property

Tags: python, properties, inspect

This is a simplified example of my actual problem.

I have a class `foo` defined like this in `foo.py`:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def bar(self):
        return True

    @property
    def baz(self):
        return False
```

Now, I want to use the `inspect` module to get the methods of the `foo` class (including `baz`). This is what I have so far in `getmethods.py`:

```
import foo
import inspect

classes = inspect.getmembers(foo, inspect.isclass)
for cls in classes:
    methods = inspect.getmembers(cls[1], inspect.ismethod)
    print methods
```

When I run this script, I get the following output (which isn't exactly unexpected):

```
[('__init__', <unbound method foo.__init__>), ('bar', <unbound method foo.bar>)]
```

So, my question is, why exactly is `baz` not considered a method and how can I modify `getmethods.py` to get the following output:

```
[('__init__', <unbound method foo.__init__>), ('bar', <unbound method foo.bar>), ('baz', <property object at 0x7fbc1a73d260>)]
```

Comment: OK, so I posted a little too soon, but I am still looking for a good reason why properties are not considered methods since the code is executed when the property is requested. For now I am doing `methods = inspect.getmembers(cls[1], lambda x: inspect.ismethod(x) or isinstance(x, property))` I am also curious if there is a better way.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `@property` decorator produces a `property` object, not a function or a method. It is this object that calls the function it has stored in the `.fget`, `.fset` and `.fdel` attributes on that object when accessed (through the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html)).

You'll have to explicitly test for that object type:

```
methods = inspect.getmembers(cls[1], inspect.ismethod)
properties = inspect.getmembers(cls[1], lambda o: isinstance(o, property))
```

or

```
methods_and_properties = inspect.getmembers(
    cls[1], lambda o: isinstance(o, (property, types.MethodType)))
```

Note that the same limitations apply to `classmethod` and `staticmethod` objects.

Comment: Excellent answer, forgot about being able to pass a tupple  to `isinstance`.